# Next.js работа с блоком по его классу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, next.js

**Доброго времени суток!**

Не могу найти информацию как работать с неким блоком по его классу в next.js. Название классов же меняется.

Моя цель растянуть блок по размеру родительского ( блок загрузки )

буду благодарен за инфу или пример!

Comment: А зачем вам работать по классу? Опишите полностью задачу, скорей всего вы не понимаете как работает react

Comment: прежде чем разбираться в реакте я наверстал шаблон с использованием jquery. Сейчас я нашел некую инфу что использовать jquery в react не желательно... теперь немного не понимаю как к примеру сделать универсальный блок с анимацией загрузки ( при ожидании того же ответа от api ). на текущий момент мне надо блоку установить высоту и ширину родителя. в jquery ``$("#loader").width($("#loader").closest("div").css("width"))``

Comment: Реакт компаненты зависят только от своих параметров передаваемых сверху, ваша задача решается установкой css стилей (heaight: 100%,width:100%) , jQuery здесь просто не нужен. Когда параметр меняется, компанент автоматически перерисовывается

Comment: JQuery в большинстве проектов обсалютно избыточен, смысл его - полифилл всех функций в браузере. С появлением сборщиков проектов и пакетным менеджером проще, лучше, быстрее работать используя нативный js

Comment: К сожалению heaight: 100%,width:100% не работает должным образом. Но я уже переделал всю реализацию блока загрузки. Как же на react реализовывать меню и прочие элементы использующие jquery?

Comment: Переделать их полностью на реакт, если в общий доступ выложете проект, смогу в свободное время помоч